# Subadditivity of cvar(R)، R is random vector

Tags: cvar

$R=(R_1,\ldots,R_n)$ is random vector in $L^1(\mathcal{R}^n)$. Then
is it true that
$$
\operatorname{Cvar}(R_1+ \cdots + R_n) \le \operatorname{Cvar}(R_1) + \cdots +\operatorname{Cvar}(R_n)? 
$$ 
Can we say $\operatorname{Cvar}(R)$ is subadditive? 
I see in the paper [portfolio optimization with copula based extention conditional value at risk](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-014-1625-3)  that 
$$
\operatorname{Cvar}(R_1+ \cdots + R_n) \ge \operatorname{Cvar}(R_1)+ \cdots +\operatorname{Cvar}(R_n).
$$

Comment: Hi Farzin and welcome. I added latex to your question, I hope I got it right. When you say "a paper" wouldn't it be good to tell the title?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes it's good. I edit now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, conditional VaR (aka Expected Shortfall) is a coherent risk measure and thus, satisfies

- Monotonicity,
- Translation invariance,
- Positive homogeneity and
- Subadditivity.

The latter means that $CVaR(R_1+R_2) \leq CVaR(R_1) + CVaR(R_2)$ which directly extends to sums of $n$ random variables. Sub-additivity captures the notion that diversification is beneficial. Note that volatility is also subadditive, but Value-at-Risk is not.

Finally, subadditivity involves $\leq$ and not $<$.

---

### Edit

The paper you mention, Krzemienowski and Szymczyk (2016), does **not** deal with Conditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR). Their paper introduces a **new** risk measure which is not coherent. Their risk measure is named Copula-based conditional value-at-risk (CCVaR). Thus, the properties of CVar do not apply. In Section 4 of the paper (Proposition 2), the authors list several properties of CCVar, one of them is *super*-additivity. Thus, $CCVaR(R_1+R_2) \geq CCVaR(R_1) + CCVar(R_2)$. This property is proven on page 224 which follows from the relationship between $CVaR$ and $CCVaR$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edit my question... Have you commente about last sentence? In portfolio optimization with copula based extention conditional value at risk 2016 paper. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-014-1625-3

Comment: I'll add my answer. Give me 5 min ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. In page 224. Author write cvar is superaddative

Comment: So, a risk-measure can be sub-additive, additive, super-additive or neither. CVaR and Volatility are examples of risk measures which are sub-additive. CCVaR is an example of a super-additive risk measure.

Comment: , and the fact that CVaR is supperadditive when larger outcomes are preferred (see, e.g., Pflug 2000). Therefore we have \begin{aligned} \hbox {CCVaR}_\beta (\mathbf {R}) \ge \hbox {CVaR}_\beta (\mathbf {1}^T \mathbf {R}) \ge \sum _{i=1}^n \hbox {CVaR}_\beta (R_i) = \sum _{i=1}^n \hbox {CCVaR}_\beta (R_i). \end{aligned}

Comment: Yes. But in page 224 he say Cvar is a superaddative. And apply in proof of the iv

Comment: \begin{aligned} \hbox {CCVaR}_\beta (\mathbf {R}) \ge \hbox {CVaR}_\beta (\mathbf {1}^T \mathbf {R}) \ge \sum _{i=1}^n \hbox {CVaR}_\beta (R_i) = \sum _{i=1}^n \hbox {CCVaR}_\beta (R_i). \end{aligned}. From page 224

Comment: This paper is main reference to my thesis, and I have problem. I need to help. I think some sentences in paper are wrong. For example author definate chorent risk measure in page 224 second paragraph with superaddative and he say Cvar is superaddative